# Java Generating Formatted Report in Text file format

Tags: java, text, format, report

Halo,

I have been looking for a way to generate a nicely formatted report in text file using java.

For example, I might need to print a report in the following format

```
A                              Monthly Report
A                               Report Name                                      Page No: 1
A Date: YYYY-MM-DD              
A
A Category                        Quantity                   Price
A -----------------               -----------------          --------------------
B Pen                             100                        $100
B Paper                           200                        $400
A
A =================                                          ====================
B Total                                                      $500
A =================                                          ====================
```

I have tried writing my own program, but I just feel that its a mess!!! So I am wondering if there are any existing library that I can use or is there a good way to implement it??

By the way, I have look around and found a library that are similar to what I want
https://github.com/iNamik/Java-Text-Table-Formatter

Just wondering if there are other options. Thanks for helping!!

====================================================================

So I have made a sample code that I probably will use to clean up my code

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(String.format("%s %50s%n", "A", "Monthly Report"));
    sb.append(String.format("%s %48s%n", "A", "Report Name"));
    sb.append(String.format("%s %n", "A"));
    sb.append(String.format("%s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", "A", "Category", "Quantity", "Price"));
    sb.append(String.format("%s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", "A", "--------------", "--------------", "--------------"));
    sb.append(String.format("%s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", "B", "Paper", 100, "$200"));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output:

```
A                                     Monthly Report
A                                      Report Name
A 
A Category             Quantity             Price               
A --------------       --------------       --------------      
B Paper                100                  $200
```

I am thinking how can I make the "Report Name" at the center and "Page No:" at the right without hard coding the int argument of the formatter (i.e. %50s, without 50, is it possible)

Comment: Post your (relevant) code, for better help.

Comment: Added sample code, what do you think? How would you suggest to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as an alternative, here is JDK based solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    printRow("A", "Category", "Quantity", "Price");
    printRow("A", "--------------", "--------------", "--------------");
    printRow("B", "Paper", 100, 200);
}

private static void printRow(String c0, String c1, Object c2, Object c3 ) {
    System.out.printf("%s %-20s %-20s %-20s%n", c0, c1, String.valueOf(c2), c3 instanceof Integer ? "$" + c3 : c3);
}
```

output

```
A Category             Quantity             Price               
A --------------       --------------       --------------      
B Paper                100                  $200
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy, you gave me some insight!

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html) is a good tool for text formating or templating. It works with plain text, HTML, JSP, XML, SQL scripts, etc. Here is a nice helloWorld [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html) about it.

The basic steps are:

1. Write your text template.
2. Initialize the Velocity Engine.
3. Insert the context that you need.
4. And render it.

Others like [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/) are more complex but really more powerful. Take a look to [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) if you need just reporting formats.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, I have take a look a the tutorial. I am wondering if there is a way to made the velocity know when to break a page? For example, a new page every 200 lines. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you have to define the template for just 200 lines, and then render the number of pages that your data fit. When you fit one page, in your code, you have to create a new file, and start over again (steps 3 and 4).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Carlos, But I think I need to make it into one file. So probably Velocity is not for my case? Anyway, thanks heaps.

Comment: What kind of file do you need? a Doc? or PDF? For those complex types Velocity is not the best option. Take a look to [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/), it might not the easiest way, but is really powerful. If you combine Latex formatting and Velocity code, you can format fancy stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the info Carlos. I need it in txt file. Thats the problem.

Comment: The problem in plain text (your txt file) is there is no way to "break the page". Your text editor could fit the text depending on the screen or paper size you want (A4, 17'x11', etc). If you need a document with pages, you need some rich format (PDF, DVI, ODT, DOC, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try iText java library i have used it for generating bills for my application.

Comment: But I thought itext can generate PDF not text file?? Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right but working on a text file and getting what you want to get would be quite messy, with more lines of code. If you have time you could try using iText and generate a pdf with which you can get the desired output.

Comment: Yes, its quite messy indeed. But it has to be done in text due to the requirements. I have use iText for some of my PDF report, its pretty good for generating PDF. Thank for helping by the way.